# iOS Date Picker - last 30 days

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

Is it possible to code a custom date picker for iOS in objective C to display only the last 30 days from today in this format: `Day, Month Day, Year`

I am trying to build a view that will display a list of item (fetched from API) based on the date selection but I only want the user to select from the last 30 days only. The entire date should be scrollable, not individual date or month.

Yes, overlapping the month.

For example:

> `Fri, May 19, 2017` ... scroll all the way back to... `Wed, Apr 19, 2017`

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, although you usually have to try doing it first...

Comment: You could just set max date == current date, and min date as == current date - 30 days. And you could use default date picker. For calculating date use 'NSDateCmponents'

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: How? Any suggestions, code snippets?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[comps setMonth: -1];
// or
//[comps setDay: -30];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:currentDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```